# What's wrong my url rewrite regex

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I use url rewrite. I add some rule like that:

```
<add name="Homes" virtualUrl="^/(.*).html" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="/Default.aspx?vsm=$1" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add name="HomeNew" virtualUrl="^/(.*)/(.*)/" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="/Default.aspx?vsm=$1&amp;idcnew=$2" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add name="HomeNewPage" virtualUrl="^/(.*)/(.*)/page-([0-9-]*).htm" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="/Default.aspx?vsm=$1&amp;idcnew=$2&amp;page=$3" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add name="HomeNewNew" virtualUrl="^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9-]*).htm" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="/Default.aspx?vsm=$1&amp;idcnew=$2&amp;idnew=$4" ignoreCase="true" />
```

I have to use all of them.
In HomeNewPage rule, I use to get catalog new page. In HomeNewNew rule, I use to get content new with $3 is url name of new.
But when go to this link: "/News/Alert/page-2" my request is "vsm=News&idcnew=Alertpage-2"
I want my request is "vsm=News&idcnew=Alert&page=2"
Please help me! What's wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: You need to escape your dot to begin with, `\.htm`

Comment: I don't understand. Could you make an example for me!

Answer (score 1):

If the url is like

- "/Default/News/Alert/page-2.html"

  ```
  Regex:-  /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/page-(.*).html
  ```
- "/Default/News/Alert/page-2"

  Regex:- /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/page-(.*)

  and you can make the new url as /Default.aspx?vsm=$2&idcnew=$3&page=$4

Basically each (.*) specify the argument like

- Default is $1
- News is $2
- Alert is $3
- But we've hardcoded the **page-** so its not an argument. So, (.*) after **page-** comes out to be argument $4

If we take your second expression ^/(.*)/(.*)/. In this case it may creates the problem with url like News/Alert/page-2 because it doesn't "/" in the end. Same is the reason with .html.
As you've not provided the url so I'm not sure about ^. But this will come only if your url will fulfill the regex from first character, however, it wont leads to any problem. You can specify or remove it.

Comment: but I have to use all of regex above. I have to use "^/(.*)/(.*)/" to get link "/News/Alert/" with page 1

Comment: You can use the regex provided by me or the last two regex provided by you if you want page=2.

The change you've to do is place '\' before .htm(or .html depending upon the URL) because backslash will escape the special character "."

Comment: I change my regex to "/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/page-([0-9-]*)\.htm" and "/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/" but when i go to "/News/Alert/page-2", my request still be "vsm=News&idcnew=Alertpage=2"

Answer (score 0):

According to me your Regex expression:

`/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/page-([0-9-]*)\.htm`

will work. But this expression

`/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/"`

wont work as it does consist of arguement for third tag(page-2). But this will work till /News/Alert. Please check your code or try to debug it according to me there is some hardcoding done. Due to which you're getting error.

I'll give you a very easy way to detect your expressions. After this you'll be able to validate your expressions appropriately.

Go to this link :  `http://www.rexfiddle.net/`

And insert your expression and in second window insert the url you want. After this you'll get captures in the end linke capture 1, capture 2, capture 3. These will be come out to be your arguements($1, $2......). See the screenshot below:

[image: Result_1st_expresssion]

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have gotten my solution. I bring this regex "/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/page-([0-9-]*)\.htm" before regex "/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/". It work fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh great!! Such type of mistake is always caught in debugging. I've told you to debug the code rather than directly running. Debugging will easily show that exactly which url pattern is ultimately coming in use. Another url is also correct but it will fulfill the url up to Alert due to which control is not going to next regex. Anyways sometimes our mind wont work with such a small mistake. This is common with developers. Enjoy!!!!